# How can I change the deployed status of a script through code? Netsuite SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Can somebody explain how can I change the deployment status for any script through code? Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the submitFields method of the N/record module.

```
record.submitFields({
    type: record.Type.SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT,
    id: scriptDeploymentId,
    values: {
        status: 'RELEASED' // or 'TESTING'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!